# Setting up Nodejs 5.10.1 on Openshift

Tags: node.js, openshift

I run a Discord bot. I am using Nodejs on Openshift. I was using their latest cartridge until I realized NodeJS 6.3 has an out of bounds bug.

I have been trying to use an earlier version of Nodejs (like 5.10.1), but I don't know how to set up the application in their cartridge.  Does anyone know how to go through the setup process?

Answer (score 0):

According to [openshift cartridge nodejs readme](https://github.com/icflorescu/openshift-cartridge-nodejs#customizing-the-nodejs-and-npm-versions), you have to set environment variables `NODE_VERSION_URL` & `NPM_VERSION_URL` if you want custom version of node/npm :

```
NODE_VERSION_URL=https://semver.io/node/resolve/4.3.2
NPM_VERSION_URL=https://semver.io/npm/resolve/3.6.0
```

Comment: Can that be set in both of their cartridges or just the 0.10.0 one and not the one labeled as lastest?  Also,where exactly do you go to set those environment variables?

Comment: This video explains environment variable settings : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5RNETUv1lIk

Comment: That video shows you the environment variables, not how to change them.

Comment: Right now I am working out of their lastest cartridge.  Nothing I have tried using export and echo commands like  export NODE_VERSION_URL=https://semver.io/node/resolve/4.4.7 or  echo NODE_VERSION_URL=https://semver.io/node/resolve/4.4.7 while sshed in works.

Comment: I tried these commands in the catridge 0.10.0 .  I see the enviroment variables changing but nothing happens. They go back to what they were before.